# Error KnpSnappyBundle / wkhtml - ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I have an incomprehensible problem.

I have used this bundle many times, and I understand the main logic to generate a pdf from a twig view.

But on my two last project i have this kind of error:

```
Error: Failed to load https://mydomain/bundles/bundle/css/bootstrap.css, with network status code 1 and http status code 0 - Connection refused

Exit with code 1 due to network error: ConnectionRefusedError
```

I have tried:

- HTTP and HTTPS url
- chmod 777 on var/cache folder - try acl
- disable   all parameters of wkhtml
- update wkhtml
- Disable extends twig view - ihave made a new file with full HTML
- Clean controller use assets
- filter / absolute_url filter / or web_url variable to prefix assets

On my development environment (Windows), i didn't have any problem.
This problem appeared when I work on production environment, based on Debian 9 with nginx, php 5.6, mariadb 10.0* and letsencrypt certificate.

I can't load any assets for now.
Does anyone have an idea??

Comment: Can you access `https://mydomain/bundles/bundle/css/bootstrap.css` from your browser?

Comment: Thanks for correction. Yes, i can access to the stylesheets or picture without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have found a workaround. I use this trick :

- create a global variable with this path :

> `pdf_url: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web'`

- then i call my assets like this :

> ```
> <link href="{{ pdf_url}}/bundles/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
> ```

Its a not the ebst solution, but its works.